# What is n+1 testing?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing

I faced an interview and he said for n+1 testing. is this any term of testing? he also said for the Devops? Please Clarify these terms.

Answer (score 8):

**N+1 Testing** (as quoted from [here](http://www.aptest.com/glossary.html)):

> A variation of Regression Testing. Testing conducted with multiple
>   cycles in which errors found in test cycle N are resolved and the
>   solution is retested in test cycle N+1. The cycles are typically
>   repeated until the solution reaches a steady state and there are no
>   errors.

**DevOps** (as quoted from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps)):

> In traditional functionally separated organizations there is rarely
>   cross-departmental integration of these functions with IT operations.
>   DevOps promotes a set of processes and methods for thinking about
>   communication and collaboration between development, QA, and IT
>   operations

DevOps is one if the roles that is a great buzz-word and everyone defines it differently. For me personally DevOps means "automate everything in your [SDLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_development_life_cycle)" to minizime human error and to optimize the release cycle and maintenance of your infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

In my world devops are the people responsible for solving operations problems.

The dev is there because there are multiple levels between the day to day technicians work and "first responders" that knows how to solve simple problems (reboot something is usually a good example).

Actually we don't have dedicated devops people, it's just a duty the engineers share.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminology used in any software testing services: **n+1 testing** is basically used to ensure a good quality cycle after reported errors are fixed. 
The quality cycles are then repeated until the solution reaches a steady state and are free from any error. Due to this, it is also often known as a 
variation of the Regression Testing(thorough testing each module of the application) as well.

The second terminology used in software testing company: **DevOps** is a movement to bring Development and Operations together– a way to communicate and collaborate across Dev and Ops. Development here is inclusive of development and test. It can be further classified as meeting the market demands for delivery of innovative new application services, doing this faster and at a lower cost without compromising on quality. So, in a nutshell, DevOps is a software development methodology which looks to integrate all the software development functions from development to operations within the same cycle.

Please refer to below link for more details on this terminology:
https://sdarchitect.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/understanding-devops-part-1-defining-devops/